# Swift 3 syntax error (Backendless)

Tags: swift3, xcode8, backendless

after updating my Xcode i'm getting error in backendless's find Syntax e.g.

```
   dataStore.find(
        { (result: BackendlessCollection!) -> Void in
            let contacts = result.getCurrentPage()
            for obj in contacts {
                print("\(obj)")
            }
        },
        error: { (fault: Fault!) -> Void in
            print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
    })
```

and the error is : `Cannot convert value of type '(BackendlessCollection!) -> Void' to expected argument type '((BackendlessCollection?) -> Void)!'`

how can i fix it ???

Comment: The compiler suggests to replace `(result: BackendlessCollection!) -> Void` with `((result: BackendlessCollection?) -> Void)!`

Comment: oh okay tell me something that i dont know about ,  how can i do it ?

Comment: What is unclear to replace code with other code?

Comment: `(result: BackendlessCollection?)` like this ? @vadian

Comment: Replace the entire expression on the left side with the entire expression on the right side.

Comment: can you explain how do we have 2 sides here ?

Comment: In your code replace the occurrence of the first type in single quotes in the error message (left side) with the second type in single quotes in the error message (right side). In my first comment I described exactly and literally what to replace. If you still don't understand that, I give up, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the code with

```
dataStore?.find(
        { (result: BackendlessCollection?) -> Void in
            let contacts = result?.getCurrentPage()
            for obj in contacts! {
                print("\(obj)")

            }
        },
        error: { (fault: Fault?) -> Void in
            print("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
    })
```